# Hide a Collection_Select Option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have dropdown built by `option_groups_from_collection_for_select(Category.all, :subcategories, :name, :id, :name)`.  How can I hide one of the categories that appears?

Comment: you should reset the whole collection using javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `Category.all`, you can pass in

```
Category.where("id NOT IN (?)", [1, 2, 3])
```

That will exclude categories with ids 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: Can a similar modification be made to exclude certain subcategories?

Comment: Subcategories belong to Categories, so I assume `:subcategories` in the `option_groups...` statement is a method which calls all subcategories belonging to a specified category.